# Apache: Hosting more than one site locally?

Tags: apache

Sites A, B, C, and localhost reside in the vhosts directory:

```
    [~/vhosts]% ls
    A/
    B/
    C/
    localhost/
```

What configuration options would I use to serve content from any one of these sites? The user should be able to enter "A" into the address bar and see A's content, "B" for B's, and "C" for C's (or "localhost" for localhost's). Right now, only localhost's content is served; and chrome thinks I'm searching for A, B, and C, or trying to access the filesystem directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Named Virtual Hosting. Here is an example of how you can do it. This is a sample. Please use the correct paths.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName A
        DocumentRoot /home/vhost/A
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName B
        DocumentRoot /home/vhost/b
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName C
        DocumentRoot /home/vhost/c
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        ServerName realservername
        DocumentRoot /home/vhost/localhost
</VirtualHost>
```